# Geopandas Cannot interpret 'Float64Dtype()' as a data type for Geopackages

Tags: python, geopandas

I want to save a geopackage file with the following Geodataframe data types

```
asset_id            string
name                string
date_completed      string
task_id              Int64
new_task           boolean
geometry          geometry
Project             string
Task ID              Int64
Task Type           string
Status              string
Asset ID            string
FFP                 string
Work Package        string
Date Completed      string
Street Address      string
Task Outcome        string
numCables           string
Length             Float64
dtype: object
```

I had The error message "Cannot interpret 'Float64Dtype()' as a data type"

I have tried converting the data type of the Length column to 'Float32' and 'Float' using astype method but still had the same error.

My code below

```
    tasks_changed = gpd.read_file(raw_file_path + 'tasks-changed-geom-lines.geojson').append(gpd.read_file(raw_file_path + 'tasks-changed-geom-points.geojson'))
    tasks_orig = gpd.read_file(raw_file_path + 'tasks-orig-geom-lines.geojson').append(gpd.read_file(raw_file_path + 'tasks-orig-geom-points.geojson'))

    tasks_merged = tasks_orig[~tasks_orig['task_id'].isin(tasks_changed['task_id'])]
    new_tasks = tasks_changed[tasks_changed['task_id'].isin(tasks_orig['task_id'])]
    tasks_all = tasks_merged.append(tasks_changed).reset_index(drop= True)
    tasks_all = tasks_all.to_crs('EPSG:27700')
    tasks_all = tasks_all.merge(asbuilt_list_report, how = 'left', left_on = 'task_id', right_on = 'Task ID')
    tasks_all['Length'] = tasks_all.length
    tasks_all = tasks_all.convert_dtypes()

    points = tasks_all[tasks_all.geometry.type == 'Point']
    lines = tasks_all[tasks_all.geometry.type == 'LineString']

    points.to_file(render_folder + '/Spatial/' + '/render_tasks_all.gpkg', layer='points', driver='GPKG')
    lines.to_file(render_folder + '/Spatial/' + '/render_tasks_all.gpkg', layer='lines', driver='GPKG')
```

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your error with `.astype(pd.Float64Dtype())`.

Try changing the data type to float64 like this (maybe this is the same as you've tried?).

If you have `nan` values in the column you might need to drop those rows, or give them some value.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
f = r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/buildings.gpkg"

df = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/buildings.gpkg")
df["randomfloats"] = np.random.random(size=df.shape[0])

df["randomfloats"] = df["randomfloats"].astype(pd.Float64Dtype())

df.head(100).to_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/float64.gpkg")
#TypeError: Cannot interpret 'Float64Dtype()' as a data type

df["randomfloats"] = df["randomfloats"].astype("float64")
df.head(100).to_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/float64.gpkg")
```

Comment: Same error, I used tasks_all['Length'] = tasks_all.length.astype("float64") ,and tried "float32" and  'float'

Comment: solved it just swapping these two lines

    tasks_all = tasks_all.convert_dtypes()
    tasks_all['Length'] = tasks_all.length.astype("float64")

so astype method should be after convert dtypes